# Suppressed the virtual mechanism by storing object explicitly as base class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, run-time-polymorphism

As you'd expect, I've arrived at a question I can't answer and I can only guess.

Runtime polymorphism is the goal, using the virtual mechanism, but the result I'm getting is as if I called the method while suppressing it; like I called the base class method.

I can only guess then that I am somehow doing that, the call is from an object that *is* a base class, although it was constructed as a derived class. So, constructed as a derived, stored as a base.

I do store this as a static base class variable within a cpp and interfaced with multiple extern functions to access elsewhere. (perhaps, that's the gotcha?)

GameScene.h:

```
class GameScene {
public:
    GameScene() { SceneInit(); }
    ~GameScene() { }

    virtual void LevelInit() { } // gcc complains w/o {}
    void SceneInit();

    virtual void UpdateLevel( const float& timeDelta ) { } // gcc complains unless {} added
    void UpdateScene( const float& timeDelta );
};

extern void NewScene( const GameScene& level );
extern void UpdateScene( const float& timeDelta );

class TestLevel : public GameScene {
public:
    TestLevel() { SceneInit(); }
    // implementation here in header
    void LevelInit() override
    {
        // level-specific initialization that is apparent at runtime
    }
    void UpdateLevel( const float& timeDelta ) override
    {
        // level-specific checks and performance
        // but, to test, I simply log "This is the test level"
    }
};

class TutorialLevel : public GameScene {
public:
    TutorialLevel() { SceneInit(); }
    // implementation here in header
    void LevelInit() override
    {
        // level-specific initialization that is apparent at runtime
    }
    void UpdateLevel( const float& timeDelta )
    {
        // level-specific checks and performance
        // debug log "This is the tutorial level"
    }
};
```

GameScene.cpp:

```
#include "GameScene.h"

static GameScene currentScene; // I am now wondering if this pattern is the problem (by explicitly storing this as the base class)

extern void NewScene( const GameScene& level )
{
    currentScene = level;
}
extern void UpdateScene( const float& timeDelta )
{
    currentScene.UpdateScene( timeDelta );
}

GameScene::SceneInit()
{
    // general init
    LevelInit(); // this _properly_ calls the subclass overridden version
    // init completion
}
GameScene::UpdateScene( const float& timeDelta )
{
    // general updating and game handling

    UpdateLevel( timeDelta ); // this was _meant_ to call the overridden version, it does not
}
```

EntryPoint.cpp:

```
#include "GameScene.h"

int main()
{
    //NewScene( TestLevel() );
    NewScene( TutorialLevel() );
    float deltaTime;
    while (gameLoop)
    {
        deltaTime = SecondsSinceLastFrame(); // pseudo
        UpdateScene( deltaTime );
    }
}
```

So, I was following a pattern that worked with SceneInit() calling LevelInit(), which is overridden in the derived classes. If I use either derived class constructor in NewScene(), I get those LevelInit() results at runtime. I thought this would be safe to use this pattern with UpdateScene().

What I see is UpdateScene() called the GameScene::UpdateLevel(), even though it is clearly overridden in the subclasses, just like LevelInit() is.

My (wild) guess is, I *am* calling UpdateLevel() as if I had explicitly cast it as GameScene. :\

And maybe, this is because I store currentScene *as* GameScene? (but then, doesn't that defeat the purpose of having polymorphism?)

I am missing something about either storing currentScene, or calling UpdateLevel(). I've tried calling like this:

```
    GameScene *s = currentScene;
    s->UpdateLevel();
```

after reading that, as a pointer, the virtual mechanism should be finding the most-derived version of the method. (but alas...)

I wish I could have found an example here or elsewhere, but my searches pointed out problems with virtual in constructors/deconstructors, or just not using the 'virtual' keyword, etc.

Comment: Unrelated: "_gcc complains w/o `{}`_" - Try `= 0` instead to make the base class abstract.

Comment: Well, `currentScene` is a `GameScene`, not `TutorialLevel` or any other derived class. You observe [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Comment: @Ted: I did try that, to no effect, but now I see why (thx!)

Comment: @Igor: Yes, and that's frustrating, because I've run into it already. (I'll learn, thank you for the explanation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentScene` **is** a `GameScene`.  You've declared it as such.  It will never be anything but a `GameScene`.  A `GameScene` is not a `TestLevel` or a `TutorialLevel`; it is a `GameScene`.  When you assign a `TestLevel` or `TutorialLevel` object to `currentScene` you are [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) it.

Polymorphism in C++ only works with pointers and references.  A pointer or reference to a `GameScene` can *refer* to a `TestLevel` or `TutorialLevel` object, but a `GameScene` object cannot *be* a `TestLevel` or `TutorialLevel`.

What this boils down to is that `currentScene` needs to be a (smart) pointer to a `GameScene` instead of a `GameScene`.  It can then point to a dynamically-allocated object of any class derived from `GameScene`.  For example:

```
static std::unique_ptr<GameScene> currentScene;

extern void NewScene( std::unique_ptr<GameScene> level )
{
    currentScene = std::move(level);
}

int main()
{
    NewScene( std::make_unique<TutorialLevel>() );
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The destructor in the base class should be made virtual too to not get slicing when destroying the `GameScene` decendant.

Comment: Thank you, Miles. I did run into object slicing before, and so palm goes to face. Thank you for the clear explanation. (of course)

Comment: @Ted: _that_ I was aware of, yes, and I will, thank you.